# Spring boot - How to Load environment specific properties when class is present in a different package

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to load enviroment specific properties base on profile. However, my main boot app is residing in a different package.

-project structure

-proj-test

```
 -src/main/java
            -com.x - AppBoot.java (Spring boot main app)
            -com.x.service - Subscriber.java 
         -src/main/resources
            -application-dev.properties
            -application-test.properties

application-dev.properties
mq.hostname=spring profile dev

application-test.properties
mq.hostname=spring profile test
```

AppBoot.java

```
package com.x
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.x" })
public class AppBoot {

    @Autowired
    private Subscriber subscriber;

    @Value("${mq.hostname}")
    private String hostName;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
     SpringApplication.run(AppBoot.class, args);
        log.debug("hostName... in Main.java " + hostName);


    }
}

package com.x.service
@Component
public class Subscriber {

    @Value("${mq.hostname}")
    private String hostName;
public Subscriber() {

        log.debug("hostName... in Subscriber .java " + hostName);
 }
}
```

Problem -       `log.debug("hostName... in Main.java " + hostName);` in AppBoot.java is getting printed with property value; however ,
`log.debug("hostName... in Subscriber .java " + hostName)` in Subscriber.java is coming as null;

Comment: At runtime, you can provide @Profile values for loading your application-<profile_name> files, Spring will automatically inject property will based on profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is, that Spring will inject your property AFTER the Bean 'Subscriber' is created!

So put your `log.debug("hostName... in Subscriber .java " + hostName);` in a different location and not in the constructor!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Added a method instead of constructor and it's working. Cheers!